# Microsoft Purview is not able to scan serverless table's fields

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, azure-purview, azure-synapse-analytics

While scanning Synapse Serverless SQL tables from Microsoft Purview, not able to reach till column-level details.

Trying to figure out what could be the reason for not scanning the table columns.

Any leads for this issue would be appreciable.

Please find below the screenshot of the scan and the result. Scan gives the
**Synapse Workspace > Serverless SL Database > Schema > Table**
[image: Purview Scan Result]

Answer (score 2):

To scan serverless database table to purview account.
Add **Reader** role to the Purview account to the synapse work space.
Create login for purview account in serverless database using below code:

```
CREATE  USER [<PurvieName>] FOR  LOGIN [purview];
ALTER  ROLE db_datareader ADD  MEMBER [<PurvieName>];
```

[image]

Add permissions to the serverless databases to scan according to your requirement. For more information you can refer below:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/register-scan-synapse-workspace?tabs=MI
2. https://www.serverlesssql.com/integrating-azure-purview-with-synapse-analytics-serverless-sql-pools/.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But It did work with Azure Service Principal account.